# Mocha cannot find global types

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mocha.js, chai

I wrote small node app with express and made global interface "LocalUser" which is essentially express response but predefined locals. Instead of importing it everywhere, I've decided to create global type

```js
declare global {
  export interface LocalUser extends express.Response {
    locals: UsersTokens;
  }
}
```

For some reason, mocha does not like it and send me

> TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
> src/router/index.ts(40,44): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'LocalUser'.

Minimal code to reproduce it:

```js
  constructor() {
    this.app = express();
  }

    this.app.all('*', function (_req, res: LocalUser) {
      const { message, code, name, status } = new NotFoundError();
      res.status(status).json({ message, code, name });
    });

    this.server = http.createServer(this.app);

    this.server.listen(getConfig().httpPort, () => {
      console.log(`Listening on ${getConfig().httpPort}`);
    });
```

Node: "18.7.0"
Mocha: "^10.0.0",

Its my first ever time using global interfaces. Is this just a normal behaviour ? Whole app is working like it should and works in js but only mocha has problems

I just removed global export. Couldn't figure out, how to properly export global interfaces

Comment: Which file did you put the global type?  Which line throws this error? Show the code

Comment: @slideshowp2 It threw error in first line where I changed type of express response.

This is file with global types https://github.com/Virus288/webStoreBack/blob/addingRabbit/gateway/src/types/global.d.ts
And this is first place that recives that erorr https://github.com/Virus288/webStoreBack/blob/addingRabbit/gateway/src/router/index.ts in 40'th line

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late, but other people still may end up here just like me.

The tests only ran when I added `global.d.ts` in `tsconfig.json` "files" attribute.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2022",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "types": ["node", "mocha"]
  },
  "files": ["global.d.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["./node_modules"]
}
```